# CSS - making semi circle and quarter circle

Tags: html, css

I need to make circles that looks like the image:

[image: nd]

My current way to make a circle :

```
.circle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

I'm not sure how to make a semi circle and quarter circle with two different colors. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205399/percent-pie-chart-with-css-only (until I find a better duplicate)

Comment: A [quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874095/css-how-do-i-make-a-1-4-circle-that-is-100vh) and a [semi-circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595147/semi-oval-with-css#)